# Combine several days of time series into one

Tags: regression, time-series, prediction

I have twenty time series from twenty days. Can I concatenate these time series into one, and run a simple linear regression on the resultant series?

Comment: Yes you can, though whether a simple linear regression would be meaningful is another matter (e.g. if you were measuring tiredness, there might be a cyclical pattern)

Comment: @Henry thanks for your feedback. I am not looking for cyclical patterns but rather patterns that probably exists within each of all these twenty series, and I'd like to make the sample as big as possible. Any thoughts on how to approach this? Perhaps it's better to run twenty separate regressions and combine the result in some way?